# Can't get variables with supabase status on github actions

Tags: github-actions, supabase, supabase-js

When I start supabase locally and run `pnpm supabase status -o env` I get a nice collection of env vars, like

```
ANON_KEY="eyJ...CJ9.eyJpc3......MTI5OTZ9.CRXP1A7WOeo....I0"
API_URL="http://127.0.0.1:54321"
DB_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:54322/postgres"
GRAPHQL_URL="http://127.0.0.1:54321/graphql/v1"
INBUCKET_URL="http://127.0.0.1:54324"
JWT_SECRET="secret-jwt-token-secret-jwt-token"
SERVICE_ROLE_KEY="eyJhb....VCJ9.eyJ...k5Nn0.EGIM96....81IU"
STUDIO_URL="http://127.0.0.1:54323"
```

I would like the SERVICE_ROLE_KEY for running some tests. I want direct access to the local database to manipulate db data, and the createClient from package "@supabase/supabase-js" requires the key.

I wrote a shell script to take the output of `supabase status -o env` to add to my env to run my tests locally. I want to run the same thing in github actions. I can get a "local" supabase started in the github action steps with `uses: supabase/setup-cli@v1` or `pnpm i` and run `supabase db start` and `supabase db reset`.
However when I run `pnpm supabase status -o env` as a github actions step I don't get the service role key or other values. I just get

```
DB_URL="***127.0.0.1:54322/postgres"
```

How can I get the SERVICE_ROLE_KEY for my tests in github actions?

I've tried using supabase CLI as mentioned above, also tried not using `supabase/setup-cli@v1` and instead running supabase commands via pnpm once dependencies installed, which made no difference. I've tried running the script immediately after supabase starts by chaining it with && (in case something was shutting down unintentionally) but no success. I updated supabase version to 1.150.0 which is up-to-date. I originally suspected my script for copying the supabase status variables somewhere the code can pick them up, but after using cat to see the file, or adding a step to run `supabase status` in github actions, the values are obviously not there.

Additionally, I may be going mad but I think it has randomly *has* worked once or twice.

Comment: The anon key and the service role keys for the local Supabase instances are static, so you can just run it once and copy and paste the value. No need to write any shell script to extract the value.

Comment: @dshukertjr but there is a different instantiation every time the github action runs as I want a fresh db for running the tests, the same as when I start one from scratch locally but new each time in ci

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I'm just telling you, the Supabase URL, anon key, and service role key for Supabase projects spun up with the CLI is static, so you don't need to dynamically fetch it every time. You may have an error in the dynamically fetching part, so just set a static value and see if it works.

Comment: @dshukertjr thanks for your reply. How can I get the service role key, as I can't seem to get anything out of running `supabase status` on gh actions? Is it possible to set it somehow by passing a flag or something?
Also, to confirm, each test run starts its own database and does not connect to anything outside the github actions runner, so that it does not interfere with concurrent tests from other branches etc. There is not a remote database all test runs would connect to, so I don't know how the same key would work unless it's deterministic, or the key can be set when the database is made

Comment: there's not a supabase url it's localhost

Comment: Just run `supabase start` on your local machine, and copy and paste the Supabase URL and the keys. Local host is still a URL. There is a Supabase URL for local Supabase instance as well.